# How can I tell a widget to maximize to fill the whole space available?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, html, widget, mobile-phones

I'm developing a widget for mobile phones using the Vodafone Mobile Widget Platform and I'm trying to get it to fill the entire screen. Using height and width to 100% doesn't seem to work as expected. Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, try this:

```
function resizeWidget() {
var availWidth = screen.availWidth;
var availHeight = screen.availHeight;
window.resizeTo(availWidth, availHeight);
}
```

Check out this document for more info:
http://widget.developer.vodafone.com/docs/Different-Resolutions-on-Mobile-Phones-v0.3.4.pdf

> During the execution of a widget, the resolution of the phone can change. For
>   example, newer mobile phones have sensors to detect whether the phone is held
>   horizontally or vertically. The Vodafone Apps Manager recognizes such changes and fires
>   a resolution-event every time there is a change. To make sure your widget is resized
>   every time the resolution changes, you can add an event listener for the resolutionevent
>   and use the resizeWidget() function as event handler:

```
widget.addEventListener('resolution', resizeWidget, false);
```

> Additionally, you should call the
>   resizeWidget-function when the widget
>   starts, because a user could start the
>   widget in landscape mode. As the
>   runtime does not raise a
>   resolution-event when this happens you
>   have to call the resizeWidget-function
>   manually.

Answer (score 1):

First, try adding height="100%" and width="100%" to your body tag as well (not just your container div).

If that does not work, try this css in addition to it.

```
html{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

If that does not work, please provide more information about the page contents that will not fill the entire screen.

Comment: It didn't work.. I'm trying to fit DIV inside a HTML to fill the available space. I think the values for 100% are reported a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   if (window.widget) {
      widget.addEventListener("widgetmodechange", function (e) {
        if (!(widget.widgetMode === "widget")) { // not on desktop
          window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
        }
      }, false);
    }
```

Baa is actually right, except you should bind the listener too "widgetmodechange". Also, check out the documentation Baa specified. It's pretty helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a "too big" width and height in the config.xml like so:

```
<width>2000</width>
<height>2000</height>
```

the widget runtime scales down the size.
To make it perfect you still need to set the CSS

```
body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

to make the widget properly scale to full width and height.
I am working with vf widgets for long and that works best.
NOte: this makes the widget tooo big on the desktop, but a widget for mobile and desktop is rare anyway imho.

Wolfram